# stat_summary on ggplot geom_line that ignores the aesthetic grouping

Tags: r, ggplot2, mean

I am not sure if stat_summary is the right way to go about this problem, but I am having a number of issues getting this plot to work.

My main issue is that I can't produce a mean line with shaded CI on this plot to summarise rainfall data.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
  
start_date <- as.Date("1985-01-01")
end_date <- as.Date("2023-02-28")
  
full_int <- interval(start_date, end_date)
  
month_seq = seq(start_date, end_date, by = "month")
month_int = interval(floor_date(month_seq, "month"), ceiling_date(month_seq, "month") - days(1))
  
df <- data.frame(interval = intersect(full_int, month_int)) %>%
  mutate(start = int_start(interval),
         end = int_end(interval),
         month = month.abb[month(start)],
         year = year(start)) %>%
  select(-interval)

df <- data.frame(cbind(df[,3:4], rnorm(nrow(df), 10)))
colnames(df)[3] <- "rainfall"
df$group <- c(rep("1985", 12), rep("1986-2023", nrow(df)-12))
  
ggplot(df, aes(x=month, y=rainfall, color=group, group=year))  +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual(values=df$group) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "gray")) +
  ylab("Rainfall (mm)")
```

What I'd like to produce is the above graph with a black dashed mean line and a shaded confidence area.

I am having trouble using `stat_summary(aes(group=Month), fun="mean", geom = "line")`

Comment: You want `group = 1`, not `group = month`. This because `stat_summary` will always summarise by each x:group combination, and the line geom will always connect within a group. So we shouldn't group by month, since then the line won't be connected between months.